# Running a PPC App on Apple Silicon

Tags: applications, apple-silicon, powerpc

Can anyone tell me if I can run [JaxoDraw](https://jaxodraw.sourceforge.io), an application for PowerPC, on a Mac with Apple Silicon? To test, I would use the [binary disc image](https://jaxodraw.sourceforge.io/download/dmg.html), as this sounds the most convenient variant to install from the [list of possible options](https://jaxodraw.sourceforge.io/quick/download.html), do you agree? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I can tell, it should run in a Java runtime environment. However, there are other apps for drawing Feynmann diagrams on macOS that are more up to date.

Comment: Thanks, what other apps do you have in mind?

Comment: I literally just googled "mac apps feynmann diagrams", and there were a whole bunch.

Answer (score 4):

The binary for this app is just a stub to execute the included java jar file.  The binary supports three different architectures:

```
$ file /Applications/JaxoDraw.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
JavaApplicationStub: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:
- Mach-O executable i386] [ppc_7400:
- Mach-O executable ppc_7400]
JavaApplicationStub (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
JavaApplicationStub (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
JavaApplicationStub (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O executable ppc_7400
```

So while your question asks about how to run PPC binaries on an Apple Silicon Mac, the problem you're experiencing is not because of PPC since the Mac should recognize the x86_64 architecture and use Rosetta 2 to execute it automatically (or at least prompt you to install Rosetta 2 first).

However, as IconDaemon mentioned, running it on an Intel Mac that should natively be able to run it still results in an error about the binary being damaged. I can think of a number of reasons behind this, however, since the binary is just a stub for running a Java jar file, the easiest solution here is to run the jar file directly!

Open a terminal and, assuming you've installed the app in /Applications, run the following:

```
java -jar /Applications/JaxoDraw.app/Contents/Resources/Java/jaxodraw-2.1-0.jar
```

These instructions assume you've previously installed java.

If you need help with that, [these instructions](https://snyk.io/blog/installing-and-managing-java-on-macos/#) will work  (I suggest the Homebrew method).

Here's an example of it working on my Apple Silicon Mac using OpenJDK 17 using that method:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that this was last updated in 2011 it quite possible won't work. Download page indicates: *The Mac disc image was built on an Intel based MacBook running OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and Java version 1.6.0_29.*

I downloaded JaxoDraw to my Intel iMac running Ventura, and although the .dmg opens the app generates this error pop-up when invoked:

[image]

Perhaps with virtualization software you may be able to run Snow Leopard on a more modern Mac, and thence be able to run JaxoDraw. I'm not familiar with setting up virtualization, so perhaps somebody can assist you with that.

Comment: Zoot alors, it does not. Quel dommage. Editing my answer to remove.